# Need help for conversion of Postfix to Infix using stack

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation

I wrote codes to convert postfix to fully-parenthesized infix as part of my homework but this code only can convert infix expression with single digit numbers. I need help for converting infix expression with numbers of 2 or more digits.

```
//Here's my code. My class doesn't use collection in JAVA.
//Classes and Interfaces for stack, list, and tree are provided.
private static final String DIGITS = "0123456789";

public static String convertPostfixtoInfix(String toPostfix)
{
    LinkedStack<String> s = new LinkedStack<>();

    for(int i=0; i<toPostfix.length(); i++)
    {
        if(DIGITS.indexOf(toPostfix.charAt(i)) != -1)
        {
            s.push(toPostfix.charAt(i)+"");
        }
        else if(toPostfix.charAt(i) == " ");{}//do nothing for blank.
        else
        {
            String temp = "";
            temp += toPostfix.charAt(i);

            String num1 = s.top();
            s.pop();
            String num2 = s.top();
            s.pop();
            s.push("(" + num2 + temp + num1 + ")");
        }
    }

    return s.top();//top() is same as peek() method.
}
```

For example, with this code,

> **input**: 4 5 - 9 2 1 + / *
>
> **output**: ((4-5)*(9/(2+1)))
>
> **input**: 40 5 - 9 20 1 + / *
>
> **output**: (9*(2/(0+1)))

Comment: You might want to show a sample postfix input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it.

First of all, a little notice. This line of code is redundant:

```
private static final String DIGITS = "0123456789";
```

If you want to check if a char is a digit, you can do it simply with

```
Character.isDigit();
```

But for simplicity I left this line as it.

Now, back to your code. In order to provide functionality for parsing multiple digit numbers, all you have to do, is to loop through the input String, when a digit is encountered, until the first non-digit character.

I've changed your code a little bit to show you the basic idea how it should work:

```
private static final String DIGITS = "0123456789";

public static String convertPostfixtoInfix(String toPostfix)
{
    LinkedStack<String> s = new LinkedStack<>();
    StringBuilder digitBuffer = new StringBuilder();  

    /* I've changed the 'for' to 'while' loop, 
       because we have to increment i variable inside the loop, 
       which is considered as a bad practice if done inside 'for' loop
    */
    int i = 0;
    while(i < toPostfix.length()) 
    {
        if(DIGITS.indexOf(toPostfix.charAt(i)) != -1)
        {
            //when a digit is encountered, just loop through toPostfix while the first non-digit char is encountered ...
            while (DIGITS.indexOf(toPostfix.charAt(i)) != -1) {
                digitBuffer.append(toPostfix.charAt(i++)); //... and add it to the digitBuffer
            }
            s.push(digitBuffer.toString());
            digitBuffer.setLength(0); //erase the buffer
        }
        //this if-else can also be replace with only one "if (toPostfix.charAt(i) != ' ')"
        else if(toPostfix.charAt(i) == ' ');{}//do nothing for blank.
        else
        {
            String temp = "";
            temp += toPostfix.charAt(i);

            String num1 = s.top();
            s.pop();
            String num2 = s.top();
            s.pop();
            s.push("(" + num2 + temp + num1 + ")");
        }
        i++;
    }

    return s.top();//top() is same as peek() method.
}
```

> **Input**: 40 5 - 9 20 1 + / * 
>   **Output**: ((40-5)*(9/(20+1)))